# Como insertar una nueva línea dentro de un row de una tabla dinámica con jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

**Explicacion del problema presentado**
Se cuenta con tabla dinámica la cual agrega filas por medio de un botón al pie de la página,lo que se desea es poder añadir dentro de cada una de esas filas por medio de otro botón una nueva fila. Y que sea optativo y manejado por el usuario final. Ejemplo:

-Fila 1
*fila 1.1
*fila 1.2
-Fila 2
-Fila 3
*fila 3.1
**Html**

````
```  <tbody >
                        <tr class="mycontainer" id="addr0">
                            <td>
                                1
                                <button id="agrega" class="btn-floating btn-success " style="border-radius: 50%;"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></button>
                            </td>
                            <td> ```
````

**Jquery**

**La primer funcion agrega las lineas principales y está funcionando a la perfección.
Pero la segunda funcion es para anidar nuevas lineas dentro de las l[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]ineas principales y no está funcionando**

````
``` 
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#add_row").click(function () {
        var numTr = $("#tab_logic tbody tr").length;
        $('#tab_logic').append("<tr id='addr" + (numTr) + "'><td> " + (numTr + 1)
            + "<button id='agrega' class='btn-floating btn-success' style='border-radius: 50%;'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></i></button></td> <td><select name='product" +
            numTr + "' type='text' style='height 60px;' class='form-control output-md' /> </td> <td><output name='descripcion" +
            numTr + "' type='number' class='form-control output-md'></td> <td><output name='costo" +
            numTr + "' type='number' style='height 60px;' class='form-control input-md'></td> <td><input name='margen" +
            numTr + "' type='number' min='0' step='0.01' style='height 60px;' class='form-control input-md' /></td> <td><output name='precio" +
            numTr + "' type='number' style='height 60px;' class='form-control output-md'/> </td> <td><input name='cantidad" +
            numTr + "' type='number' min='0' style='height 60px;' class='form-control input-md'/></td> <td><output name='precioTotal" +
            numTr + "' type='number' style='height 60px;' class='form-control output-md' /> </td> <td><input name='tipoCambio" +
            numTr + "' type='number' min='0' style='height 60px;' class='form-control input-md'/></td> <td><output name='precioFinal" +
            numTr + "' type='number' style='height 60px;' class='form-control output-md'/></td> <td><textarea name='notas" +
            numTr + "' type='text' style='height 60px; width: 150px; resize:none;' class='form-control textarea-md'/> </td> </tr>");

    });



   $("#agrega").click(function () {
        var i = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
        var numTr = $("#tab_logic tbody tr").length;
        $("#addr" + (i)).append("<tr id='newrow" + (numTr) + "'><td>"
            + "</td><td><select name='Extra" + numTr + "' type='text' placeholder='' style='height 60px;' class='form-control output-md' /> </td><td><output name='" +
            numTr + "' type='number' placeholder='' class='form-control output-md'></td><td><output name='" +
            numTr + "' type='number' placeholder='' style='height 60px;' class='form-control input-md'></td> <td><input name='" +
            numTr + "' type='number' min='0' step='0.01' placeholder='' style='height 60px;' class='form-control input-md' /> </td> <td><output name='" +
            numTr + "' type='number' placeholder='' style='height 60px;' class='form-control output-md'/> </td> <td><input name='" +
            numTr + "' type='number' min='0' placeholder='' style='height 60px;' class='form-control input-md'  /> </td> <td><output name='" +
            numTr + "' type='number' placeholder='' style='height 60px;' class='form-control output-md'  /> </td> <td><input name='tipoCambio" +
            numTr + "' type='number' min='0' style='height 60px;' placeholder='600' class='form-control input-md'  /> </td> <td><output name='precioFinal" +
            numTr + "' type='number' style='height 60px;' placeholder='' class='form-control output-md'  /> </td> <td><textarea name='notas" +
            numTr + "' type='text' style='height 60px; width: 150px; resize:none;' placeholder='Notas' class='form-control textarea-md'  /> </td> </tr>");

    }); 

 ```
````